# why printing the value after casting from request.getAttribute to int causing NullPointerException?

Tags: jsp

```
int age = (Integer)request.getAttribute("age");
out.println(age);
```

Why the 2nd line is throwing NullPointerException ??

Comment: I suspect, it's the first line that throws exception.

Comment: Actually the second line throws exception. 
I have already tested

Answer (score 0):

```
out.println(age);
```

The only thing that can be null in this statement is `out`. So, if you get a NullPointerException at this line, it means that `out` is null.

Comment: I dont think out is null.The following code is working fine.

Integer age = (Integer)request.getAttribute("age");
out.println(age);

Comment: Then it's not this line that's causing the exception. If only you posted the stack trace, we would know instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have that attribute existing when you execute it later. Problem could be with your processing sequence and not with the code!
Try following method of ServletRequest:

getAttributeNames() 
          Returns an Enumeration containing the names of the attributes available to this request.

For the first time, it is retrieving the attribute value, and further if it is not retriving that means problem with execution sequence. You do not have request attribute with name "age"